# Alternate video player for browsers

Tags: video, web-browser, media-player

Is there any way to have a video player such as VLC replace the built-in player that exists within web browsers for HTML5 content?

I would like to be able to watch YouTube (and preferably also other HTML5-based) videos at varying speeds (i.e. 1.5x, 2x, etc.) - without needing to download them completely and then watch them via a separate program. Is there any addon/browser/player that can make this work?

I am looking for a free Windows-based solution, but I would be interested to know if this is possible on other systems as well.

Comment: for firefox, look down these addons: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=vlc There seem to be plugins which will enqueue videos into vlc, and one which will let you 'preview' videos before it's finished downloading.

Comment: @user3791372 - based on your suggestion I'll try to provide an answer that I also want to have here for reference

Comment: @user3791372 - two of the addons in that list worked very well, the rest seem outdated. I'll complete the list

Comment: Worth pointing out now that the native youtube player seems to allow you to adjust the speed of the video. Great for studying / revising.

Answer (score 1):

The idea would be to open an embedded video in an external video player. (For Windows: VLC, MPC-HC, MPC-BE, PotPlayer, Windows Media Player; for Linux: VLC, `mpv`, SMPlayer; on Mac: VLC). A good way to do that is to use **Firefox addons**. (there were also some Chrome addons, but now Chrome seems to go in different direction by [removing NPAPI plugins](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213033?hl=en)):

**[FlashGot](http://flashgot.net/)**

Made to send videos to external download managers: can be set to send the video to an external video player. After installing and adding the players as described in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/819188/162573), make it easily accessible like so: open the 'customize' options for Firefox and drag&drop the needed icon in a visible location on the toolbar (that will then be visible only during media play).

[image]

Start the video and that icon will become visible.

[image]

**Do not left-click that!** (For some sites like youtube multiple streams are available for a title and left-clicking starts them all, as FlashGot is intended for downloading and this is a 'download them all' feature.)

Right click on that and select 'Flashgot options' if you want to select between multiple video players if the case:

[image]

[image]

Right-click the icon to select the stream to play (different are available on Youtube).

[image]

**Cross-platform, different video players, different (HTML5 and Flash) websites**.

---

**[OpenWith](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-with/?src=ss)**

Made to open links in other internet browsers: can open a link into a video player.

[image]

[image]

**Cross-platform, multiple video players, tested in Youtube** (other sites may work, although none that I tested does).

---

**[Watch with MPV](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/watch-with-mpv/)**

Made to start internet video in [mpv video player](https://mpv.io/). Adds a toolbar icon and a context menu entry and can use a short-key to start. It is supposed to be set to work with other players too (but trying VLC it doesn't seem to work well).

[image]

**Cross-platform, mpv-based but can be set for other video players, different (but not many) websites**

---

**[VLC Youtube shortcut](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vlc-youtube-shortcut/?src=search)**

Adds a context menu entry to start playing a Youtube video in VLC.

[image]

**Cross-platform. Youtube-only, VLC-only.**

---

**[YT2Player](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yt2player/?src=search).**

[image]

**Cross-platform, Youtube-only, different video players** (but only one can be set at the same time; in FlashGot and OpenWith you can add and select between different players).

---

Last two addons were suggested by a comment made by [user3791372](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/7253/user3791372). Other addons in the link included in the comment are outdated and even buggy.